# Azure Mobile Service restriction on Tables

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

Is it possible to read, update, ... objects of some different granularity than database tables? Let's say any complex business objects like contracts which do not cosist of only one table? 
I would like to encapsulate the business logic in my backend. My client should not know anything about a database schema.

How can we do that using Azure Mobile Service.

Comment: It is hard to tell that by just reading the statements. Anyways, you should expose the API (JSON, XML etc) to the mobile devices. This way, your business logic will take care of the data translation to either tables or NoSQL data. It will be easier than you think, and the answer is already in your question... Just too generic. :-)

Comment: It was basically about, how to handle data that are more complex than a single table. It's about relationships and so on. The book posted below looks like a good piece to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Mobile Apps does not support relationships.  As a result, you will need to generate something that looks like a table that when updated does the right thing.  SQL Views with triggers on insert/update/delete tends to work.  However, most people want M:M relationships, which aren't easily formulated this way.

For more information, see chapter 3 of the book - http://aka.ms/zumobook